# Require a simple password for an offline HTML5 app

Tags: html, authentication, passwords, offline

I am creating a simple web gallery similar to [StickyAlbums](http://www.stickyalbums.com/) and would like to include an optional password (**not** a username/password combo). This password doesn't need to be really secure, just enough to give protection from accidental viewing of the gallery if a password is used.

StickyAlbums has an optional password that must be reset through a link in the app itself in order for it to require the password next time it is opened. This works whether the app is accessed online or offline. This is the functionality I would like to duplicate.

What is the best way to include a password that works like that? Thanks!

P.S. I am fairly well versed in HMTL and JavaScript, but HTML5 is new territory for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [javascript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). 
Something like this:

```
  var password;

  function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) { c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "="); }
    if (c_start == -1) { c_value = null; }
    else {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1) { c_end = c_value.length; }
      c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
  }

  function setCookie() {
    password = prompt("create your new password");
    document.cookie = "password="+password;
  }

  function checkCookie() {
    var check = prompt("enter password");  
    var pw = getCookie("password");
    if(pw==check) {
      alert('your password was correct');
    } else {
        alert('that is the wrong password');
    }
  }
```

Here's an quick example http://jsfiddle.net/v3Byr/1/

Comment: Would I create a DIV element that covers everything and the correct password removes it? Or would I be able to use a splash page that checks for the cookie first?